# Sorting from first lowest number

Tags: python

What I need is to define sort_by_level(gradebook) where

```
sort_by_level(gb)

[('CS1010S', 'A+'), ('MA1101R', 'C'), ('SSA1207', 'B+'), ('CS2020', 'A')]
```

sorts the first number within the gradebook. For example, 'CS1010S' first number is '1'.
The tricky part for me is the 'SSA1207' where the first number is 1 in the 4th position.

My helper:

```
def getting_code(module):
    for i in range(len(module)):
        if module[i] in [ "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]:
            return module[i]
```

Thanks a lot!

Edit: My question is slightly different from the rest in the sense that I'm looking to arrange by using the FIRST NUMBER in the eg: MODULE[0] as compared to the others that are sorting using Grades eg: A/B/C

Comment: hint: Use the `re` module with `sorted(list, keys=<put_something_here>)`

Comment: The same homework has been asked several times over the past week.  Try searching a bit.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first number out of the string by using [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) with a [`isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) check.

Then, use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) with a custom `key` function where you extract the first digit out of the string of the first item of every tuple in a list:

```
def sort_by_level(gb):
    return sorted(gb, key=lambda x: int(next(i for i in x[0] if i.isdigit())))

data = [('CS1010S', 'A+'), ('MA1101R', 'C'), ('SSA1207', 'B+'), ('CS2020', 'A')]
print sort_by_level(data)
```

prints:

```
[('CS1010S', 'A+'), 
 ('MA1101R', 'C'), 
 ('SSA1207', 'B+'), 
 ('CS2020', 'A')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remember the keys to prevent computation of the first digit multiple times:

```
grades = [('CS1010S', 'A+'), ('MA1101R', 'C'), 
          ('SSA1207', 'B+'), ('CS2020', 'A')]
grades = [(int(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), g[0])[0]), g) for g in grades ]
print sorted(grades)
```

*Gives:*

```
[(1, ('CS1010S', 'A+')), (1, ('MA1101R', 'C')), 
         (1, ('SSA1207', 'B+')), (2, ('CS2020', 'A'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expression like this

```
my_list=[('CS1010S', 'A+'), ('MA1101R', 'C'), ('SSA1207', 'B+'), ('CS2020', 'A')]
import re
print sorted(my_list, key=lambda (item, _): int(re.search(r"\d", item).group()))
# [('CS1010S', 'A+'), ('MA1101R', 'C'), ('SSA1207', 'B+'), ('CS2020', 'A')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`for`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) loop and check if each entry is a digit using the builtin [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit).

```
>>> string = 'SSA1207'
>>> for k in string:
...     if k.isdigit() == True:
...             print 'The first digit is:', k
...             break
... 
The first digit is: 1
>>>
```